# O que significa essa expressão *=

Tags: php, javascript

Gostaria de saber qual é o significado de `*=` tanto no PHP e Javascript:

Tenho uma função JS e estou convertendo para o PHP, daí apareceu isso `*=` mas eu não tenho ideia o que isso faz.

Na questão da função está certo. Gostaria apenas de entender para que serve.

```
$b *= 200;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Resposta Simplificada**

Isso é uma forma abreviada de:

```
$b = $b * 200;
```

da mesma forma existe as abreviações para soma, divisão e multiplicação

```
$b = $b - 200;
$b -= 200;
$b = $b + 200;
$b += 200;
$b = $b / 200;
$b /= 200;
```

**Resposta mais detalhada**

Isto é um `Operador Combinado` onde se combina uma atribuição simples (passando o valor de uma variável a outra) com uma operação aritmética com a variável que irá armazenar a atribuição (o resultado).